# Argument isn't numeric error using Perl

Tags: perl

I'm teaching myself Perl from the Learning Perl 6th ed book and I don't understand an error I'm getting. I'm writing a program to report the access and modification times of all the files in my current directory in YYYY-MM-DD format. In all my trials, I kept getting an error saying

```
Argument "2014-03-16" isn't numeric in printf at ex17-3.pl line n.
```

where n was whatever line contained the `printf` call.

Eventually I just copied and pasted the book's answer into my editor and ran it, just to see that it worked, but this resulted in the same error

```
Argument "2014-03-16" isn't numeric in printf at ex17-3.pl line 15.
```

Here's the code

```
#!usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use 5.012004;

foreach my $file (glob('*')) {
  my ($atime, $mtime) = map {
    my ($year, $month, $day) = (localtime($_))[5,4,3];
    $year += 1900;
    $month += 1;
    sprintf '%4d-%02d-%02d', $year, $month, $day;
  } (stat $file)[8,9];
  printf "%-20s %10d %10d\n", $file, $atime, $mtime;
}
```

Can anyone explain why I get this error? Is it the version of Perl that I'm using, maybe?

Comment: Please don't post images of code. It makes it impossible to copy and paste what you have written to try it for ourselves

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$atime` and `$mtime` are strings, but you are trying to print them with `%d`. I think you should print them with `%s`. Printf is not able to figure out how to interpret the date string as a number, which is a reasonable error, IMO.

Comment: Note that, in Perl, it's fine to use a string where a number is required. As long as that string *looks like* a number, Perl will convert it transparently for you. However `2014-03-16` doesn't look like a number, and Perl is saying that it doesn't know what to do with it to match the requirements of the `%10d` format field.

Answer (score 1):

Btw, your code can be simplified a little by the use of the core library [`Time::Piece`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html) (available since Perl version 5.8):

```
#!usr/bin/perl

use Time::Piece;

use warnings;
use 5.012004;

foreach my $file (glob('*')) {
  my ($atime, $mtime) = map {
    localtime($_)->strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
  } (stat $file)[8,9];

  printf "%-20s %10s %10s\n", $file, $atime, $mtime;
}
```

Comment: `corelist Time::Piece` says "Time::Piece was first released with perl v5.9.5"

Comment: TY @DaveCross  I was using this as my source: [`Solve almost any datetime need with Time::Piece`](http://perltricks.com/article/59/2014/1/10/Solve-almost-any-datetime-need-with-Time-Piece) as I was still relying on just Date::Time and other modules until recently.  I also didn't know about the command `corelist Time::Piece`, which the next item in the [google search results](https://www.google.com/#q=How+long+has+Time%3A%3APiece+been+part+of+perl+core%3F) did mention: [`A Cautionary Tale - Time::Piece on Fedora`](http://perlhacks.com/2012/08/a-cautionary-tale/)

Comment: Never trust anything you read on the internet :-) Oh, except the chap who wrote that "A Cautionary Tale" piece - I hear he's pretty accurate!